# c++ while loop do max 1 time

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
class knygos {
public:
    int nr;
    char pavadinimas[25];
    char autorius[25];
    int egz_sk;

    void go_to(int x, int y) {
        COORD c;
        c.X = x - 1;
        c.Y = y - 1;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
    }

   void knygu_sarasas() {
       ifstream myFile("data.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
       while (myFile.read ((char *) this, sizeof (knygos))) {
           go_to(2,6);
           cout << nr << endl;
           cout << "Pavadinimas" << pavadinimas << endl;
           cout << "Autorius" << autorius << endl;
           cout << "Egzemploriai "<< egz_sk << endl;
       }
       myFile.close();
    }
};

void main() {
    knygos ob;
    ob.knygu_sarasas();
}
```

Why when I use function `go_to(2,6);` while loop work only 1 time, when i not use this function loop work normaly (6 times) I not know where is problem, plese help guys ;)

Comment: Surely this doesn't even compile! Please post real code.

Comment: What is the `read` function call supposed to do? `(char *) this`… my eyes are burning.

Comment: Problem is not there, see when I not use `move_cursor(2,6); function while loop work 6 times, but when I use this function loop work only ą tomes

Comment: There is a problem there, it's just not causing the symptom you're working on right now. And what are we supposed to tell you about `move_cursor` when we haven't seen it yet? Probably it does some I/O causing the subsequent `read` operation to fail.

Comment: move_cursor is function of same class like while loop

Comment: @Tomas: I only meant that you post a relevant piece of code taken from your actual, working program. `sizeoff` cannot possibly compile (unless you have some bastardly macro or function somewhere, which you *should* include).

Comment: See I edit main post, maybe now you can help :)

Comment: My C++ is a bit rusty; is blasting arbitrary data over an object UB if it's a POD type?

Comment: Reformatted the code because it was making me cry :p PS: make your data members private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you realize that if you set the cursor **IN** the loop to the (2, 6) position, all interation will wite to the **SAME** place, effetivly overwriting each other, and only producing "one" output for all 6 or many cicles?

Answer (score 0):

You can using ncurses library for type of input such as keyboard/mouse and and output such as screen.If you use mvprintw() family functions,You can set X and Y same as gotoxy in DOS.
I forgot cout and cin and use ncurses library, you can learn it from [here.](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Comment: One of good advantage of this family, having getch() family functions.